# Calling a ScriptMethod on form submission?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, postback

When I call a ScriptMethod from an ASP.NET button using the OnClientClick property, the ScriptMethod returns 95% of the time (alert box shows), and the page submits.

If I call the method from a HTML input button, the ScriptMethod returns 100% of the time, but of course the page doesn't submit. If I change the type to submit, I'm back to the succeeding 95%.

Do I have to change my approach, and call submit from javascript after my ScriptMethod returns, or is there a way to make this succeed 100% of the time? By success, I mean actually returning 100% of the time before the form submits. The ScriptMethod never actually fails.

Page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="ScriptServiceMadness._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>    
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            <Services>
                <asp:ServiceReference Path="Chewbacca.asmx" />
            </Services>
        </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="VerifyPostbackTextBox" runat="server" Text="true" />        
        <asp:Button ID="SubmitFormButton" runat="server" OnClientClick="attack()" Text="Works 90%" OnClick="SubmitFormButton_Click" />        
        <input type="button" id="InputButton" value="Works 100%" onclick="attack()" />
    </div>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function attack()
        {
            ScriptServiceMadness.Chewbacca.ShootImperialProbeDroid(true, speak, youvefailedme);            
        }

        function speak(result)
        {
            alert(result);            
        }

        function youvefailedme(error)
        {
            alert(error);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

namespace ScriptServiceMadness
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void SubmitFormButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            VerifyPostbackTextBox.Text = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

ScriptService:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Web;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Threading;

namespace ScriptServiceMadness
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Chewbacca
    /// </summary>
    [ScriptService]
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [ToolboxItem(false)]
    public class Chewbacca : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [ScriptMethod]
        [WebMethod]
        public string ShootImperialProbeDroid(bool letHanDoIt)
        {
            if (letHanDoIt)
            {
                return "rrrroooorrrr";
            }
            else
            {
                return "rrrraaaarrrr";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

One thing of interest...I removed the bool parameter from the SciptMethod while writing this question, and it seems to work 100% of the time. This of course may be coincidence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the script method executes asynchronously you cannot guarantee that it will return before the form is posted back. The changes it will not will increase when you deploy online and your users have slower connection to the web service. What I may suggest is you postback manually by calling the __doPostBack routine once you get the response .

Answer (score 0):

You forgot :

```
using TheForce;

namespace Luke {
}
```